# Time limit exeeded

Tags: python, теория-чисел, факторизация

[Задача](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=861&ins=1#solution) на acmp.ru "Осколки"

> На Землю надвигается страшная угроза, к нам летит облако из N огромных
> астероидов. Известно только то, что все они одинакового размера. У
> учёных есть ракеты, способные уничтожить астероиды, каждая такая
> ракета характеризуется зарядом m – натуральным числом от 1 до N. Но, к
> сожалению, неизвестно, как каждая из ракет поведёт себя при
> столкновении с астероидом, поэтому было принято решение запустить по
> одной ракете каждого вида. И только после столкновения стало известно,
> что ракета с зарядом m после уничтожения астероида образует осколки в
> количестве, равном наибольшему общему делителю чисел m и N. Помогите
> узнать, сколько осколков упадёт на Землю, у Вас совсем мало времени!
>
> Входные данные
>
> В единственной строке входного файла INPUT.TXT содержится натуральное
> число N – количество запущенных ракет и взорванных ими астероидов (1 ≤
> N ≤ 10^18).
>
> Выходные данные
>
> В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите количество осколков, которые
> упадут на Землю.

Не проходит 8й тест из-за превышения времени(2,203 с.)

```
# -*-coding: cp866 -*- 
s=0;
def gcd(a, b): 
    while b: a, b = b, a % b 
    return a 
try:
  f = open("input.txt",'r')
  n = int(f.readline())
  f.close
except IOError: print ("No file") 
for i in range((int(input()))): s+=gcd(i,n);
print("s=",str(s));
with open("output.txt", 'w') as f1: f1.write(str(s)); 
f1.close;
```

Ошибка "Time limit exeeded"
(Время: 2 сек. Память: 16 Мб Сложность: 88%)

Comment: Текст задачи - в вопрос. И вопрос должен быть развернутым.

Comment: вот бы кто догадался давать переменным в коде такие же имена, как в задаче, чтобы другие не гадали, где тут что.

Comment: В описании задачи не вижу, чтобы где-то было про ввод через input - там точно что-то вводится?

Comment: @insolor Я делал через файл, и можете посмотреть на самом сайте условие.

Comment: @Roman у вас есть в коде чтение из файла, но значение для range считывается через input: `for i in range((int(input())))`. В условии на сайте ничего не написано, про то, что что-то будет вводиться через input.

Comment: @insolor # -*-coding: cp866 -*- 
s=0;
def gcd(a, b): 
    while b: a, b = b, a % b 
    return a 
try:
  f = open("input.txt",'r')
  n = int(f.readline())
  f.close
except IOError: print ("No file") 
for i in range((int(input()))): s+=gcd(i,n);
print("s=",str(s));
with open("output.txt", 'w') as f1: f1.write(str(s)); 
f1.close; Оно и так не проходит

Comment: "Оно и так не проходит" - а что поменялось? input как был, так и остался.

Comment: я не то отправил

Comment: for i in range(n): s+=gcd(i,n);

Answer (score 2):

Задача довольно сложная.

Данная сумма [эквивалентна](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai%27s_arithmetical_function)

```
Sum{по всем d: делителям n} (d * Fi(n/d))
```

Где `Fi()` - [функция Эйлера](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_euler_function)

Таким образом, потребуется выполнить факторизацию `n` на простые множители.
Для вычисления функции Эйлера потребуется факторизация `n/d` - а она уже фактически есть как разность факторизаций `n` и `d`

---

Нагуглил [более простой способ](https://forthright48.com/gcd-sum-function), основанный на той же функции Эйлера под капотом.

Опять же выполняем факторизацию на простые в виде (ai - степени простых)

```
n = p1^a1 * p2^a2 *....pk^ak
```

И тогда результат

```
SumOfGCD = Prod[i=1..k} ((ai+1)*pi^ai - ai*pi^(ai-1))
```

Пример

```
n = 9876543212345678
fac = factors(n)
print(fac)
res = 1
for x in fac:
    res *= x[0]**(x[1] - 1) * (x[1] * x[0] + x[0] - x[1])
print(res)

[(2, 1), (11, 1), (73, 1), (101, 1), (137, 1), (709, 1), (626861, 1)]
890508372065319735

n=2276680122000
[(2, 4), (3, 8), (5, 3), (173501, 1)]
294146224081200

n=6
[(2, 1), (3, 1)]
15
```

Comment: Я немного не понял, можете добавить это в код?

Comment: Если у вас проблемы "с кодом", с реализацией несложных формул, то зачем берётесь за задачи, требующие неплохого владения теорией чисел (сложность 88%, надо полагать, довольно высока)?